# Add malayalam font in mPDF in Laravel application

Tags: laravel, pdf, mpdf

I am using mPDF in my Laravel application. My pdf file comes with both English and Malayalam languages. But Malayalam content not loading properly. I tried to add new font, but it's always showing `missing OTL table` error. Here is my code.

config/pdf.php

```
return [
'mode'                  => 'utf-8',
'format'                => 'A4',
'author'                => '',
'subject'               => '',
'keywords'              => '',
'creator'               => 'Laravel Pdf',
'display_mode'          => 'fullpage',
//'tempDir'               => base_path('../temp/'),
'tempDir'               => __DIR__.'/../temp/',
//'tempDir'               => __DIR__.'/../storage/framework/pdf/',
'pdf_a'                 => false,
'pdf_a_auto'            => false,
'icc_profile_path'      => '',

'font_path' => base_path('resources/fonts/'),
'font_data' => [
    'malayalam' => [
        'R'  => 'ECBThinkal.ttf',    // regular font
        'B'  => 'ECBThinkal.ttf',       // optional: bold font
        'I'  => 'ECBThinkal.ttf',     // optional: italic font
        'BI' => 'ECBThinkal.ttf', // optional: bold-italic font
        'useOTL' => 0xFF,    
        'useKashida' => 75, 
    ]
    
   ]
];
```

view.blade.php

```
<html>
   <?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');?>
<head>
<style>
    body {
        font-family: 'malayalam', sans-serif;
    }
</style>
```

I am not pasting full code. When I try to create pdf it returns error `Unable to set font "D:\xampp\htdocs\xxxxx\resources/fonts//ECBThinkal.ttf" to use OTL as it does not include OTL tables (or at least not a GDEF table).`

Tried some other fonts also, but still this error is showing.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are missing in your config.

```
'autoLangToFont'        => true,
```

Reference: https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/automatic-font-selection.html